# Extracting LinkedIn recommendations for your website

Tags: linkedin-api

How can I extract or get the LinkedIn recommendations for my website? Is there any plugin or PHP script?

Comment: Can you clarify the type of recommendation you're looking for?

Comment: Sure, for example the recommendations of other people about you in Linkedin.

Comment: An ejample http://bit.ly/pAzTpd

Answer (score 11):

You can extract the recommendations using the [LinkedIn API](https://developer.linkedin.com/apis), specifically the [Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api). Rough steps are:

1. Create an application;
2. Authenticate yourself via OAuth;
3. Make a call to the API (via JavaScript or some other language via the REST interface) to retrieve your recommendations. A sample call that will do this:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(recommendations-received)`

In terms of doing this with PHP, there is a free library, along with demo scripts, here:

http://code.google.com/p/simple-linkedinphp/

Answer (score 3):

LinkedIn ended their support for the most of the apps. You must be in a partner program in order to be able to get full profile information.

Comment: I realize that this is an old thread, but do you have any link to verify this?