# How to get Linkedin recommendations using Linkedin API?

Tags: php, linkedin-api

How to get LinkedIn recommendations in PHP?

How to retrieve `educations, recommendationsReceived, skills, twitterAccounts` and user profile data from linkedIn API?

**How to Output this type get:**
(this is Dummy Data)

```
{
  "educations":  {
    "_total": 1,
    "values":  [
       {
        "degree": "MCA",
        "endDate":  {
          "year": 2010
        },
        "fieldOfStudy": "English",
        "id": 68487593,
        "schoolName": "Computer Studies",
        "startDate":  {
          "year": 2007
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "firstName": "Firstname",
  "id": "k4AWESnyv",
  "recommendationsReceived":  {
    "_total": 1,
    "values":  [
       {
        "recommendationText": "Good Morning.",
        "recommender":  {
          "firstName": "First Name",
          "headline": "Student",
          "lastName": "patel",
          "pictureUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/0_V24ZjoIoyZaEFqbRgzWupnoHNs6ORLamtWosKRfVQR3qkss3v",
          "publicProfileUrl": "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/linkedinuser/17/5ba/23a"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "skills":  {
    "_total": 9,
    "values":  [
       {
        "id": 2,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "PHP"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 3,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "Joomla"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 4,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "Magento"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 7,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "WordPress"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 8,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "AJAX"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 9,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "MySQL"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 10,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "Web Design"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 13,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "E-commerce"
        }
      },
       {
        "id": 14,
        "skill":  {
          "name": "HTML5"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "twitterAccounts":  {
    "_total": 1,
    "values":  [
       {
        "providerAccountId": "123456789",
        "providerAccountName": "twitterusername"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting recommendations on Linkedin for your site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803919/extracting-recommendations-on-linkedin-for-your-site)

Answer (score 6):

To get the linkedin recommendations, you need to do the following:

1. Authenticate the user via OAuth.
2. Retrieve the profile data by making an API call.

To  retrieve `educations, recommendationsReceived, skills, twitterAccounts` along with user profile data, your API call would be:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,skills,educations,recommendations-received,twitter-accounts)?format=json`

Comment: Is there a link for more info on this?